# Is there a limit to the amount of data in a spatial join in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I am using Quantum GIS and trying to spatially join a point grid with polygons that are overlapping. If I get the sum of intersecting features, then I can get a good raster value. Well, every time I attempt the spatial joing with the summary, I get the following python error:

> An error has occured while executing Python code:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools/doSpatialJoin.py", line
>   99, in accept
>       res = self.compute(inName, joinName, outPath, summary, sumList, keep, self.progressBar)   File
>   "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools/doSpatialJoin.py", line
>   214, in compute
>       if k == "SUM": atMap.append(sum(numFields[j])) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'QPyNullVariant'
>
> Python version:
>   2.7.4 (default, Sep 26 2013, 03:23:21)  [GCC 4.7.3

Any idea why I may be getting this error? I am trying to join 65,527 points to 121 polygons in this case.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the amount of data.

This is an error caused by NULL values in your data.

<strike>This should be considered a bug. Please [open a ticket](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Bugreports) for this.]</strike>

This has been fixed in commit [f9e0093](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/f9e0093ce70b06130a98c1e20278d0746ddb930c). Unfortunately just a bit too late to hit QGIS 2.2.0. It would be very nice if you could test this fix (e.g. with tomorrow's master build) and give a feedback here.

As a workaround (for QGIS <= 2.2.0), one can (temporarily) replace NULL values with 0 if the only value of interest is the sum (will/may obviously lead to wrong results for other aggregates like min/max/avg/median)

Comment: I had been running from the 2.0.x binary, but I'm working on building from source now. I'll update with my results if I ever get the make to work properly... running into issues with python2.7

Comment: If it's only for this fix: There are master/testing/nightly (all refer to the same) builds [around for all major platforms](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html). You may as well just replace the file `/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools/doSpatialJoin.py` on your system with [the one from git](https://raw.github.com/qgis/QGIS/master/python/plugins/fTools/tools/doSpatialJoin.py)